# can I clear routerReuseStrategy store manually?

Tags: angular, angular6

my custom reuse-strategy cache visited routes. when I logout and then login by a different user I want to clear store with my cached routes. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing. i'm trying to find resolve